# How to perform variable consolidation having If/else conditions in between in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I am trying to consolidate all the variable declarations in my javascript file. 
I.E

```
var a = 5,
    b = 10;
if (true) {
    var c =15;   // * Line in question
}
```

Do I need to initialize **c** using var to avoid it becoming global variable? Is there any other way to take it as a part of variable consolidation? 
In other words, Is there a way to continue with declaring the variable using just one var keyword having If/else condition in between?

Such as,

var a,
    b;
if (true)
    c;  // Dont want this as a global variable

Thanks,

Comment: it is global...

Comment: @Jonasw - Correct, Is there any way to continue declaring variable using just one var keyword having if/else in between?

Comment: declaring variables inside of an if is simply bad style...

Comment: agree with @Jonasw on the above comment

Comment: you can use the new ES6 declaration using "const" and "let" keywords

Comment: Got it. This answers my queries. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
var a = 5,
    b = 10;
if (true) {
    var c = 15;
}
```

is identical to the following code as far as the JavaScript engine is concerned:

```
var a, b, c;
a = 5,
b = 10;
if (true) {
    c = 15;
}
```

`var` is "hoisted" to the top of the function it appears in.

If you want to consolidate `var`s, you can do what I've shown in the second block above.

> Do I need to initialize c using var to avoid it becoming global variable?

You need to *declare* it (`var c`). You don't have to initalize it (the `= 15` part is the initialization, which is really an assignment when used with `var` since `var` happens earlier and separately).

---

Side note: JavaScript now has the `let` keyword (as of ES2015 aka "ES6"), which has block scope. So if `c` is never used except **inside** that `if` block, you could do this:

```
let a = 5,
    b = 10;
if (true) {
    let c = 15;   // * Line in question
}
```

...which scopes `c` nicely to only the code that uses it.

---

Side note #2: If you keep your functions small, there's not a lot of reason to combine your `var`s at the top of the function. It's one of the many style arguments that keeping functions small makes go away. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation . One more question,                        if(true) {var c =10;} and if(true{let c =10;}  has any difference? Both ways, c can only be accessible inside if block ?

Comment: @Gendaful: No, again, `var` is hoisted to the top of the function in which it appears. So with the `var` version, the `c` variable exists throughout the entire function, it's just that it only gets assigned a value within that `if` block. With `let`, the variable only exists within the `if` block, not outside it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at hoisting:

```
var a = 5,
b = 10;
if (true) {
     var c =15; 
}
```

Will be hoisted to:

```
var a,b,c;
a=5;
b=10;
if (true) {
     c =15; 
}
```

So there are two possibilities: Declare c outside and assign it inside of the if, or use let:

```
var a = 5,
b = 10;
if (true) {
     let c =15; 
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do many of us want to declare the variable inside the if block? The primary reason is the baggage from classical programming languages like c++ and c# etc. This is because these languages have scoping rules that govern block level scope and variables within them.

However, javascript ES5 (prior to ES6) had only function level scoping. This is the reason people say that the variables are hoisted. 
This is another way of saying that no matter where you declare a variable inside a function, it will be visible at the function level. What does this mean to the question asked? It means that due to the language rules, we as programmers gain nothing by declaring a variable inside if/else.
This is why ES6 has let keyword that allows block level scope that fits well with the mental model that people have coming from classical languages.

Hope this adds more light to illuminating answers already given.